# TSP in R, wrong tour length

Tags: r, traveling-salesman

I have got simple distance table(matrix):

```
datalist <- data.table(V1=c(0, 28635.76, 16496.41), V2=c(28635.76, 0, 22032.14), V3 = c(16496.41, 22032.14, 0))
```

When I am testing TSP algorithm from R package "TSP" I am getting result of tour length:  98559.14. But when I am adding distances "by hand" my result is 16496.41+22032.14+28635.76 = 67164.31 = tour_length(tour). 
Rest of my code:

```
  tspObj <- ETSP(datalist)
  tour <- solve_TSP(tspObj, start = 1, method = "two_opt")
  #tour length
  tour_length(tour)
```

Anyone knows why I get two different results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `E` in `ETSP` stands for "Euclidean". This function interprets `V1`, `V2`, `V3` as 3 points in 3-dimensional Euclidean space, not as the rows of a distance matrix (as you seem to be thinking). Note that:

```
> sum(sqrt(sum((V1-V2)^2)) + sqrt(sum((V1-V3)^2)) + sqrt(sum((V2-V3)^2)))
[1] 98559.14
```

There is another constructor called simply [TSP](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/TSP/versions/1.1-4/topics/TSP). You can't directly feed it a data table, but the following works:

```
> tspObj <- TSP(as.dist(datalist))
> tour <- solve_TSP(tspObj, start = 1, method = "two_opt")
> tour
object of class ‘TOUR’ 
result of method ‘two_opt’ for 3 cities
tour length: 67164.31
```

Comment: TSP needs symmetric martix, or in dist. But still is giving result like ETSP.

Comment: Why use `data.table()` rather than `rbind()` or `cbind()` to directly create a symmetric matrix? It is evidently coercing your data table into a `dist` object by computing pairwise distances. Perhaps experiment with `dist()` or `as.dist()` with your data until you get what you want.

Comment: @Adamek  I downloaded the package and was able to get it to work as expected, as the edit above shows